# Python limited to one core on fedora linux

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, fedora

I have octa core processor (amd fx-8120 on 3.4GHz), and I tried to use multiprossing library on fedora 18, It created all process but i didnt work, It only used one core. What I have to change on my python code? Thanks

```
import time
def fibo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return (fibo(n-2)+fibo(n-1))
start_time = time.time()
print fibo(35)
print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fibo()` function is not threaded. Throwing the `multiprocessing` module at it won't magically make it run in parallel with itself.

Answer (score 1):

this is a processor bound task in pure python.  see: [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: is it a software problem? or I can use all cores in python?

Comment: The **GIL** only affects *threads* (the `threading` module), not processes (the `multiprocessing` module).

Comment: So what i have to change on my code to use all cores? b-w-baugh

Comment: B.W. Baugh, it affects the main thread in this case.